# Using a list from a fact within Prolog rules

Tags: list, prolog, fact

I am currently writing a rail line program but am having a little trouble using lists that come from facts. I am quite new to Prolog and so far have written the following facts and rules:

```
location(euston, [northernLine]).
location(warrenStreet, [victoriaLine, northernLine]).
location(warwickAvenue, [bakerlooLine]).
location(paddington, [bakerlooLine]).

hasCommonLine(Location1, Location2, Line) :-
    location(Location1, Line),
    location(Location2, Line).
```

The idea is for the rule to return the name of the line(s) that the two locations have in common. This works if I try `hasCommonLine(warwickAvenue,paddington,Line).` , however it returns false if I try `hasCommonLine(euston,warrenStreet,Line).`.

I suspect this is because the rule only checks the first element of the lists, therefore only compares `[northernLine]` and `[victoriaLine]` rather than checking every element in the list. Any guidance to accomplish this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if `Line` is a member of both lists:

```
 hasCommonLine(Location1, Location2, Line) :-
     location(Location1, Lines1),
     location(Location2, Lines2),
     member(Line, Lines1),
     member(Line, Lines2).
```

Then, if you need to find all the lines common between two locations, you would simply call

```
 ?- findall(X, hasCommonLine(euston, warrenStreet, X), Y).
 Y = [northernLine].
```

Answer (score 2):

> I suspect this is because the rule only checks the first element of the lists.

No, the program checks if the **two lists are identical**. So only if both `Line`s are completely equivalent (same elements, same order) they match.

It is rather *un-Prolog* to specify the list of lines using a list. Usually they represent it as a list of facts like:

```
location_new(euston,northernLine).
location_new(warrenStreet,victoriaLine).
location_new(warrenStreet,northernLine).
location_new(warwickAvenue,bakerlooLine).
location_new(paddington,bakerlooLine).
```

So here `warrenStreet` occurs twice: once with the `victoriaLine` and once with the `northernLine`. Then you could simply write:

```
hasCommonLine(Location1, Location2, Line) :-
    location_new(Location1, Line),
    location_new(Location2, Line).
```

Nevertheless since this is not the case, you could write a helper predicate `location_helper/2`:

```
location_helper(A,B) :-
    location(A,L),
    member(B,L).
```

and then define:

```
hasCommonLine(Location1, Location2, Line) :-
    location_helper(Location1, Line),
    location_helper(Location2, Line).
```

Comment: I'm guessing they specify it as a list because it is an exercise. The next exercise might well be "add 20 lines".

Comment: Thank you for correcting my suspicion and for such an informative answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your rule needs improvement.
Right now, it checks if the two locations have *exactly the same* list of lines.

What you should do, is make a rule that checks if there is overlap between the two. You could use a predicate that checks the intersection of the two lists.

It would look something like this:

```
hasCommonLine(Location1,Location2, CommonLines):-
    location(Location1,Line1),
    location(Location2,Line2),
    intersection(Line1,Line2,CommonLines).
```