# Prolog rule to find which stations are on a particular Underground line

Tags: prolog

I'm currently trying to answer a segment for a piece of coursework. As the title indicates I need to create a rule to state which stations are on a particular line. I've already inputted the data needed in previous pieces of the script and have been trying to make use of the `findall` function. Clearly something has gone wrong, can you guide me as to where I'm going wrong?

**Please don't give me a complete answer.**

Here is the segment of code.

```
station(kennington,northern).
station(embankment,northern).
station(tottenhamcourtroad,northern).
station(warrenstreet,northern).
station(euston,northern).

/*Q3 which stations are on a particular Underground line? */

line(Line, ListOfStations) :-
    findall(Line,X),
    findall(X,ListOfStations).
```

Comment: Related question: [How can I write rules for the following questions and facts in Prolog?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41742556/1243762)

Comment: Related question: [Prolog Tube Line Task](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41706982/1243762)

Comment: Related question: [Using a list from a fact within Prolog rules](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41698790/1243762)

Comment: From the tag I see you are using `SWI-Prolog` and in the question you mention the `findall` function, which leads me to think [findall/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=findall/3) but your `findall` has only two arguments. Can you provide the code for your `findall`. For an example of what I am was expecting with `findall` see [WikiBooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Prolog/Bagof,_Setof_and_Findall).

Comment: @GuyCoder: I think it is obvious that the OP wanted to use a `findall/3` but forgot to query for stations, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The usage of findall you are looking for is `findall(+Template, :Goal, -Bag)` (as Guy Coder said: [findall/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=findall/3)).

What this means is find each set of variables that satisfy `:Goal` as written (in this instance, you are looking for `station(X,Line)`), then place them in the `-Bag` list (which you call `ListOfStations`) using the `+Template` (which, for you, is presumably `X`, to create `[X1,X2,X3|...]`).

Put them all together and you get (spoiler warning, I guess?):

> `findall(X, station(X,Line), ListOfStations).`

Which will output:

> `[kennington, embankment, tottenhamcourtroad, warrenstreet, euston]`

Where the list is ordered by the order of the facts.

**Additional Information:**

If your template looks like `[X]` instead of just `X`:

> `findall([X], station(X,Line), ListOfStations).`

Your output looks like this:

> `[[kennington], [embankment], [tottenhamcourtroad], [warrenstreet], [euston]]`

And you could even make it look like `(station,X)` to get:

> `findall((station,X), station(X,Line), ListOfStations).`

Giving you:

> `[(station,kennington), (station,embankment), (station,tottenhamcourtroad), (station,warrenstreet), (station,euston)]`

And if you want to find every combination of stations on a line, the `:Goal` can be compound as well, like so:

> `findall((X,Y), (station(X,Line),station(Y,Line),X\=Y), ListOfStations).`

Giving you something silly like this:

> `[(kennington,embankment), (kennington,tottenhamcourtroad), (kennington,warrenstreet), (kennington,euston), (embankment,kennington), (embankment,tottenhamcourtroad), (embankment,warrenstreet), (embankment,euston), (tottenhamcourtroad,kennington), (tottenhamcourtroad,embankment), (tottenhamcourtroad,warrenstreet), (tottenhamcourtroad,euston), (warrenstreet,kennington), (warrenstreet,embankment), (warrenstreet,tottenhamcourtroad), (warrenstreet,euston), (euston,kennington), (euston,embankment), (euston,tottenhamcourtroad), (euston,warrenstreet)]`

Which I hope gives you a good idea of how powerful findall is.

Comment: perhaps you meant `station(X)` as a template?

Comment: @WillNess That would also work - I was just indicating that the template can look like pretty much anything!